# How to redirect onclick while using iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

I had to use an iframe to stop the page from reloading before the action was completed. However, I need it to refresh after the action is taking place. I tried two methods for this, refreshing the page and redirecting to the same page.

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_name']) {
   //Action
   location.reload(); 
  //I also tried 
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

HTML:

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" border="0px solid white" style="display:none" name="iframe1" id="iframe1"></iframe>

        <form action="index.php" method="post" target="iframe1">
         <input type="submit" href="" style="margin-top:5px" name="btn_name" class="btn btn-success" value="Enter">
            </form>
```

Thanks for your help. All input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['btn']` doesn't post anything because it's a class.

Try `$_POST['installer4_btn']` instead.

Comment: And for good measure it'd be 'header('Location: index.php');`

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in your page where your iframe is(this is using jquery)

`$('#iframe1').load(function() { 
     if (this.contentWindow.location.href === 'http://location_redirected_in_php') {
        window.location.href = '/redirect_location';
     }
});`

Comment: this actually adds a listener to your iframe whenever it reloads, so if you page reloads after success submission or process in php, all you need to do is get the location it will end up and check it that if the iframe has that url, reload your parent page.